# What does this wish stroke mean?

Tags: kanji, calligraphy

[image]

Its a paper stroke hanging below a iron bell

The hiragana transelates to no furin but i cant find the translation or meaning for the top two kanji

Answer (score 9):

「趣味{しゅみ}の風{ふう}りん」 *a wind-bell as a hobby*
This phrase seems only a sales message, not someone's wishes.
The main purpose of the hanging is to have the bell ring by the wind's breeze, not to write wishes on it.

I'll tell you about the characters written on the hanging.
There are roughly three styles of script to write *kanji*s in handwriting, especially by a writing brush: they are 楷書体 (*kaisho-tai*) style, 行書体 (*gyohsho-tai*) style and 草書体 (*sohsho-tai*) style.

The characters on the slip of paper hanging are written in:
**趣**：*kanji* in 行書体 (*gyohsho-tai*) style
**味**：*kanji* in 行書体 (*gyohsho-tai*) style
**の**：*hiragana*
**風**：*kanji* in 草書体 (*sohsho-tai*) style
**り**：*hiragana*
**ん**：*hiragana*

**楷書体(*kaisho-tai*)** [Regular script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script) (traditional Chinese: 楷書; simplified Chinese: 楷书; pinyin: kǎishū; Hepburn: kaisho), also called 正楷 (pinyin: zhèngkǎi), 真書 (zhēnshū), 楷體 (kǎitǐ) and 正書 (zhèngshū), is the newest of the Chinese script styles (appearing by the Cao Wei dynasty ca. 200 CE and maturing stylistically around the 7th century), hence most common in modern writings and publications (after the Ming and gothic styles, used exclusively in print).

**行書体(*gyohsho-tai*)** [Semi-cursive script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-cursive_script) is a cursive style of Chinese characters. Because it is not as abbreviated as cursive, **most people who can read regular script can read semi-cursive**. It is highly useful and also artistic.

**草書体(*sohsho-tai*)** [Cursive script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursive_script_(East_Asia)) (simplified Chinese: 草书; traditional Chinese: 草書; pinyin: cǎoshū), often mistranslated as grass script (see Names below), is a style of Chinese calligraphy. Cursive script is faster to write than other styles, but difficult to read for those unfamiliar with it. It functions primarily as a kind of shorthand script or calligraphic style. **People who can read standard or printed forms of Chinese may not be able to comprehend this script**.

[image]
[image]

Comment: While admiring all the effort put into this great answer, I can't actually make sense of the suggestion that the phrase means  "*a wind-bell as a hobby*". It might make sense, if "professional wind bells" existed, or if there was a broad movement ...hmmm for collecting wind bells (?). But standalone? It could also mean a wind bell bringing pastime or leisure, or a refined wind bell. I have no clue, but "as a hobby" looks weird.

Comment: "a hobby bell" might make more sense as literal translation. I would imagine this to mean a bell that rings leisurely as opposed to on command (it could ring on command if you pull on the tag, but that's beside the point)

Comment: ＠psosuna: 「風鈴｛ふうりん｝」がbellだけ十分ならpsonunaさんの翻訳が良いと思います。しかし、「風鈴」はa wind-bellだと思いますのでa hobby bellは少し変だと思います。「趣味の風鈴」は「趣味としての風鈴」という意味だと思いますので、私は、a wind-bell as a hobbyとしました。こまかなnuanceは分かりませんが、a wind-bell for a hobby でもいいのかも知れません。